# Why won't Silverlight 5 obey HTTP 302 messages

Tags: silverlight, post, httpclient

I have written an application written in C# within Silverlight 5 (using VWD 2012).

This application 'logs in' to websites (quite legitimately) using HttpClient GetAsync and PostAsync requests.

However .. when I run the application and it encounters a website which returns an HTTP 302 response (i.e. "Object moved to here"), my application simply hangs and will not 'follow' the response re-direction to the new URL.

How do I know it is Silverlight 5 which is the problem?

Because when I run the SAME application OUTSIDE of Silverlight 5 (e.g. as a console application) - it works correctly.

How do I know it is these 302 messages which are the problem?

Because when I run this SAME application INSIDE of Silverlight 5 to another website which doesn't return a 302, it works correctly.

Have I tried to trap the error using 'catch (HttpRequestException hre)' or just 'catch' ?
Yes, but no error appears to be caught or trapped  =:O((

Here are the offending lines:

```
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriPOST, content); // This 'hangs'
}
catch (HttpRequestException hre)   // Nothing is ever caught
{
    Console.WriteLine(hre.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)               // Nothing is ever caught
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I have a genuine security certificate attached to the Silverlight 5 application (which works perfecly, because I can access websites which DON'T return me a 302) ....

I have 'AllowAutoRedirect' set to 'true' in the HTTPClient handler.

Any ideas?  Why does this work OUTSIDE of Silverlight 5 but not within Silverlight 5?

Comment: Does it work when you use WebClient instead of HttpClient? Are you using the Silverlight http stack or the Browser stack to perform the web request?

Comment: No, I haven't tried WebClient instead of HttpClient (I chose HttpClient because I understood it was the 'new' way to go ...)  Do you think WebClient would make a difference?  And I'm fairly sure I am using the Http stack ... isn't that the default (?) insofar as I haven't performed any prior configuration to use the Browser stack. I run it as an Out-Of-Browser application with elevated privileges btw.

Comment: Well, following the lead from dotMorten, I did try a WebClient solution and it failed - more or less the same problem as the HttpClient solution I originally tried.  However (!) perseverance paid off - and I trued an HttpWebRequest solution and I managed to get it working i.e. my Silverlight application logs in to the remote website and the HttpWebRequest solution therein seems to be un-fazed by the 302 'Response Redirect' which seemed to scupper the other two solutions.

Comment: Well, following the lead from dotMorten, I did try a WebClient solution and it failed - more or less the same problem as the HttpClient solution I originally tried.  However (!) perseverance paid off - and I trued an HttpWebRequest solution and I managed to get it working i.e. my Silverlight application logs in to the remote website and the HttpWebRequest solution therein seems to be un-fazed by the 302 'Response Redirect' which seemed to scupper the other two solutions.

Comment: I am going to shelve the HttpClient solution for the time being and re-write this part of the application to use HttpWebRequest.  Several things seem to puzzle me though - why is Silverlight 5 networking so poorly and (sometimes) ambiguously documented?  There are many Http protocol header values and settings which are prohibited in Silverlight, but could be interpreted (from the documentation) as being valid.  The second aspect is .. why are there SO MANY different 'approaches' to driving the protocol between a client application and a remote website?. It is as if obsfucation is 'de rigeur'

Comment: Most of the headers are restricted because they are managed by the browser and Silverlight doesn't get to set them. If you want full control, you can switch from the browser stack to the client stack and have SL manage the web request, which will give you more control (but also lose out on gzip, caching, some security options etc)